# XPATH ORACLE how to get values from parent node

Tags: oracle, xpath

My query ouhgt to transform XML into a table (data set):

```
with   UFD_data as 
(select xmltype(
'<Document>
  <Lines>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
      <Fields>
        <Field>
          <FieldName>A1</FieldName>
          <FieldType>B1</FieldType>
          <FieldValue>C1</FieldValue>
        </Field>
      </Fields>      
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
      <Fields>
        <Field>
          <FieldName>A2</FieldName>
          <FieldType>B2</FieldType>
          <FieldValue>C2</FieldValue>
        </Field>
      </Fields>      
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
    </Line>
  </Lines>
</Document>
') xml_data from dual)

select xml_data,
       x.*
from   UFD_data sd
cross  join xmltable('/Document/Lines/Line'
                     passing sd.xml_data
                     columns "LineNumber"               varchar2(20)   path 'LineNumber',
                             "FieldName"                varchar2(255)  path 'Fields/Field/FieldName',
                             "FieldType"                varchar2(255)  path 'Fields/Field/FieldType',  
                             "FieldValue"               varchar2(4000) path 'Fields/Field/FieldValue'
                    ) x
```

but there is a problem when added more than one group with fields:

```
with   UFD_data as 
(select xmltype(
'<Document>
  <Lines>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
      <Fields>
        <Field>
          <FieldName>A1</FieldName>
          <FieldType>B1</FieldType>
          <FieldValue>C1</FieldValue>
        </Field>
        <Field>
          <FieldName>D1</FieldName>
          <FieldType>E1</FieldType>
          <FieldValue>F1</FieldValue>
        </Field>
      </Fields>      
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
      <Fields>
        <Field>
          <FieldName>A2</FieldName>
          <FieldType>B2</FieldType>
          <FieldValue>C2</FieldValue>
        </Field>
      </Fields>      
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
    </Line>
  </Lines>
</Document>
') xml_data from dual)

select xml_data,
       x.*
from   UFD_data sd
cross  join xmltable('/Document/Lines/Line'
                     passing sd.xml_data
                     columns "LineNumber"               varchar2(20)   path 'LineNumber',
                             "FieldName"                varchar2(255)  path 'Fields/Field/FieldName',
                             "FieldType"                varchar2(255)  path 'Fields/Field/FieldType',  
                             "FieldValue"               varchar2(4000) path 'Fields/Field/FieldValue'
                    ) x
```

The error returned :

```
ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic TYPE mismatch: expected singleton SEQUENCE
```

How to change XPATH expession to get results like below:

| LineNumber | FieldName | FieldType | FieldValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B2 | C1 |
| 1 | D1 | E2 | F1 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 |
| 3 |  |  |  |

How to change XPATH expession to get results like below:

| LineNumber | FieldName | FieldType | FieldValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B2 | C1 |
| 1 | D1 | E2 | F1 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 |
| 3 |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1):

Use two `XMLTABLE`s, passing `Fields` from the first to the second:

```sql
SELECT l."LineNumber",
       f.*
FROM   UFD_data sd
       CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '/Document/Lines/Line'
         PASSING sd.xml_data
         COLUMNS
           "LineNumber" varchar2(20) PATH 'LineNumber',
           Fields       XMLTYPE      PATH 'Fields'
       ) l
       LEFT OUTER JOIN XMLTABLE(
         '/Fields/Field'
         PASSING l.fields
         COLUMNS 
           "FieldName"  varchar2(255)  PATH 'FieldName',
           "FieldType"  varchar2(255)  PATH 'FieldType',  
           "FieldValue" varchar2(4000) PATH 'FieldValue'
       ) f
       ON (1 = 1)
```

Which outputs:

| LineNumber | FieldName | FieldType | FieldValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | B1 | C1 |
| 1 | D1 | E1 | F1 |
| 2 | A2 | B2 | C2 |
| 3 | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wgTPD62q)